# How to test a stubbed function called with certain shape of object as argument in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

How can I test that a stubbed function is called with an object in a certain shape as the argument?

For example, I was trying to do something like

```
cy.get('@submitStub').should('have.been.calledWithMatch', {
  dateRange: {
    startDate: `The actual value here doesn't matter`,
    endDate: '',
  }
});
```

Of course the above code doesn't work as expected. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Meaning, you don't care about what value the `startDate` is, just that it's defined?

Comment: @dwelle Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    const obj = {
      method () {}
    };
    cy.stub(obj, 'method').as('stubbed')

    obj.method({
      dateRange: {
        startDate: `The actual value here doesn't matter`,
        endDate: '',
      }
    });

    const isNotUndefined = Cypress.sinon.match( val => {
      return val !== undefined;
    });

    cy.get('@stubbed').should('have.been.calledWithMatch', {
      dateRange: {
        startDate: isNotUndefined,
        endDate: isNotUndefined,
      }
    });

    // or
    cy.get('@stubbed').should('have.been.calledWithMatch', {
      dateRange: Cypress.sinon.match( obj => {
        return obj &&
          'startDate' in obj &&
          'endDate' in obj
      })
    });

    // or
    cy.get('@stubbed').should('have.been.calledWithMatch', {
      dateRange: Cypress.sinon.match.has("startDate")
        .and(Cypress.sinon.match.has("endDate"))
    });

    // or
    cy.get('@stubbed').should('have.been.calledWithMatch', arg1 => {
      // do whatever comparisons you want on the arg1, and return `true` if 
      //  it matches
      return true;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I cannot get `cy.stub` to work in any instance.